# TeXworks: synctex works only partially

Tags: texworks, forward-inverse-search

I've got a document that compiles without error or warnings (and looks about right) but for some segments of the document synctex doesn't seem to be working.  What could be wrong?

The document consists of one root `.tex` file which `\input`s a bunch of others.  Synctex works for all these sub-documents - except for one.  In practice, this means I can Ctrl-Click in the viewer and find the appropriate spot both in parts of the text before and after this particular subdocument.  Conversely, I can Ctrl-Click in the editor and jump to the right spot in the view in all subdocuments but this one.

However, when I Ctrl-Click on a part of the output corresponding to this particular subdocument I get the following error popup: `Cannot read file "E:/emn/uni/Thesis/doc": Access is denied.` in the TeXworks viewer.  The path in this error message exists but is a directory: namely the one containing the tex files.

- All filenames consist of only latin letters, numbers, and underscores and the extension `.tex`.  The problematic file is called `G2MLVQ_9_Refinements.tex` whereas a (working) file is called `G2MLVQ_7_Implementation.tex`
- I can't make a small example which fails - small examples don't fail; however the order of files seems to matter, so perhaps something in an earlier file is affecting synctex later on... (once I've isolated this, I'll update the question).
- Concerns MiKTeX 2.9 and the bundled TeXworks version 0.4.3 r.857.

I'm stumped: what could be going wrong?

**Edit:** user59152 tried to isolate the error:

> It is virtually impossible to create a minimum working example (MWE) for this problem, so I have posted a ["jing" (screencast) movie illustrating the error](http://screencast.com/t/nihk0DZND). You can see the file names at the tops of the windows. The one being edited (`Introduction.tex`) comes BEFORE the file that can't be opened using inverse search (`SourceAndSinkFreeContinuumRVtracking.tex`). The screencapture movie confirms that `\clearpage` restores inverse search capability, but fouls up the layout of the document, so this problem appears to remain unsolved.  I'm using TeXworks version 0.4.4 r.1003 and MikTex 2.9.

Comment: We need more detail. What version of TeXworks and TeX system (MiKTeX, TeXLive) do you use? What are the file names involved: are there spaces or special characters in the name of the problematic file?

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Personally, I have often solved my own problems in the process of reducing the amount of code actually required to reproduce the problem.  So, in this case try removing most of the code before and after and try to minimize the size of the included file.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to make a MWE, which I haven't managed to yet.

Comment: There are no weird characters in the filename; everthing is in `[A-Za-z0-9_]` followed by `.tex`.  Path contains no spaces and no weird characters either.  Oh, and the `\input` command uses the same capitalization as the filename to avoid windows case-insensitivity issues.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with synctex and multiple files, using the TikZ-package for drawing. It turned out that uncommenting a certain `\input{tikzpicture.tex}` in a (working) file that is parsed just before the problematic file 'resolves' the problem. Currently I'm trying to figure out which part of the TikZ-code causes the problem. It seems to have no problems with a minimal TikZ-example as an `\input{tikzpicture2.tex}` and synctex also links correctly into `tikzpicture2.tex`.

Comment: Hey, that sounds promising!

Comment: Do you get any hints when you look at the `.synctex` (or un-gzipped `.synctex.gz`) file with a text viewer/editor?

Comment: It is virtually impossible to create a minimum working example (MWE) for this problem, so I have posted a "jing" (screencast) movie illustrating the error at <a href="http://screencast.com/t/nihk0DZND">http://screencast.com/t/nihk0DZND</a>. You can see the file names at the tops of the windows. The one being edited (Introduction.tex) comes BEFORE the file that can't be opened using inverse search (SourceAndSinkFreeContinuumRVtracking.tex). The screencapture movie confirms that \clearpage restores inverse search capability, but fouls up the layout of the document, so this problem appears to rem

Comment: I just run into a similar problem - causes are different apparently, but "jump to source" works for me when from the main document TeX window instead of PDF window. Just mentioning this - maybe someone has similar cause of the problem...

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problem after moving the last section from one capter_y.tex to somewhere in chapter_x.tex. After moving, the chapter after chapter_y.tex, chapter_z.tex, failed when trying "jump to pdf"/"jump to source"

I have no idea why this worked, but solved the problem by including \clearpage before the failing chapter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,norsk,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
...
\input{chapter_x}
\input{chapter_y}
\input{chapter_z}
```

to

```
...
\input{chapter_x}
\input{chapter_y}
\clearpage
\input{chapter_z}
```

In my case, using \include{.}, instead of \input{.} for both the chapter preceding the problem chapter, and the problem chapter itself also worked, since

```
\include{.} == \clearpage \input{.} \clearpage
```

I'm using 
MikTex 2.9, Windows 7 32bit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped, actually :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was facing the same problem while in my case the documents were more nested and the chapter facing the problem was the first one among the ones in the same depth. The `\clearpage` trick worked.

Answer (score 6):

I have ran across a similar problem on WinEdt and SumatraPDF. After trials and errors, I found that if I use \input for both files (e.g., the first one contains a "complicated" tikzpicture, and the second one is where a synctex search error may occur), instead of \include, the error goes away. If I need \newpage or \clearpage for the second file, I use the command inside the file, not before the \input command in the main file.

For an example of "complicated tikzpicture", you can try the example "Fancy tables with TikZ", a blog by Stefan Kottwitz:

http://texblog.net/latex-archive/graphics/tikz-table/

Hope my experience might be any of help.

Here is an MWE:

**main file**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} %% to construct a complex tikzpicture
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{document}
\section{Main File}
Three more tex files will be added below.

% part1 contains a tikzpicture
\input{synctex-part1}

%\newpage, \clearpage or \include may break synctex
\input{synctex-part2}

\newpage  % now without it, synctex in part 3 is broken
\input{synctex-part3}

\end{document}
```

**synctex-part1.tex**

```
\section{Part 1}
a complex tikzpicture

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (mynode) {\Large This tikzpicture may cause synctex failure.};%
%% without pgfonlayer, synctex works fine regardless include or input
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}%
%% draw a box
\draw[rounded corners,top color=red,bottom color=black!40!red,draw=white]
    ($(mynode.south west)-(0.1,0.1)$) rectangle ($(mynode.north east)+(0.1,0.1)$);
\end{pgfonlayer}%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You can write anything in synctex-part2.tex and synctex-part3.tex to test.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'm using only `\input` already anyhow, and the "main" file contains virtually no content beyond `\input` already - just the title and TOC, not even usepackages etc.

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne, I added an MWE, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me, renaming the chapter file did the trick.

I renamed...

- The file `ch1_intro.tex` to `ch1_intro2.tex` (in the `chapters` directory)
- The include reference in the main document `\include{chapters/ch1_intro2}`