# Texmaker inverse search error

Tags: texmaker, back-referencing

I am using Texmaker to write a paper on Windows 10. My paper contains several sections, so I write each section on a separate tex file and use input to include them into the main file:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\input{introduction}

\section{Conclusion}

\input{conclusion}

\end{document}
```

On Texmaker, I use Option->Define Current Document as 'Master Document' to define my main file as master, so that I can compile the whole paper while editing, say, the Introduction section.

While reading the pdf file produced by Texmaker on the right, I often want to go back to the latex code (at exact location) on the left to edit, so I use Ctrl + Mouse click. Here comes the error. Say if I am editing the Introduction, and use Ctrl and click on a text of that section, an error message appears "You do not have read permission to this file". Strange enough, if I click "OK" to acknowledge the error message, then the exact location of the code on the left of Texmaker where I want to edit is shown.

I think there should be a way to get rid of that error message so I don't have to click OK every time, but I could not find a solution. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**: I've found this similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34931/texworks-synctex-works-only-partially). One possible solution from that link is to use \include instead of \input, or put \clearpage before \input. This will get rid of the error message but also create an unwanted blank page. For editing purpose, I can just use \include and switch back to \input once I am done. The problem is still not completely solved though.

Comment: `texstudio` works nicely with `\input` :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  It seems to go away when I delete all the auxiliary files (logs, bbl files, etc.), but it comes back after a few compilations.