# TeXmaker gives this weird error: You do not have read permission to this file

Tags: errors, pdf, texmaker

I have my document build-up with a main, where I include files which are located in a lower directory, e.g. `docdir/main.tex` - links to: `docdir/chapters/chapter1.tex`. And in TeXmaker I use the masterdocument option (Options - Define current document as Master Document), such that I can easily navigate in the PDF using ctrl-space and ctrl-click in the code and pdf, respectively. However, now I have this super odd error...

If I ctrl-click in chapter 2, I get immediately directed to the corresponding code. However, for chapter 3, I get the errormessage "You do not have read permission to this file", while in my file properties (windows) there is no read-only or whatever odd setting compared to the other files. I also tried to make a copy of the file, but this did not help either.

Do any of you know how to fix this, it is very annoying...

Texmaker version: 5.0.4 (edit: It was 5.0.2, I updated, but it did not solve it)

**EDIT :** I found this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350266/texmaker-inverse-search-error), where the error is solved by using `\include{chapters/chapter1}` instead of `\input{chapters/chapter1}`, however this leaves an ugly white page. But it solves the convenience problem :P

Comment: The latest version of [TEX*MAKER*](https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) is version `5.0.4`, update it and check if the problem persists.

Comment: This did not solve the problem. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Contact the maintainer and ask for support.

Comment: The weird thing is... after adding some text with the `include` method, and changing it back to `input`, the error does not occur anymore... magic!

Comment: I got this error and "fixed" it by exiting Texmaker, deleting all the log, aux, and output files for my document, and then re-opening and re-compiling.